# How to print value of a variable by NSLog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A really basic question, I have recently started exploring Objective C and Trying to mess with one example code. However just for debugging purpose I want print value of NSString variable on console. How do I achieve this?

Basically I am a java developer, So I am looking something similar as...

```
String hello = "world!";
System.out.println(hello);
```

My variable in this foreign language(Obj-C) is...

```
NSString *hello = ...calling a method to return string...
```

Any hint will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
NSLog(@"Value of hello = %@", hello);
```

Comment: I have a code completion shortcut for this one: `NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));` note that it gives you the class name, **NOT** the file you're in.  If you have a rich inheritance hierarchy (most don't), it could be in a superclass file when it says "[subclass methodName]"

Comment: If you find the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and find `stringWithFormat:`, it provides links to [Formatting String Objects (the basics)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) and [String Formatting Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) - peruse them!

Comment: also note that in the example above (and using `po` in the debugger), the `-(NSString *)description;` method is invoked on the object.  You can override that method to provide something interesting.  (The easy way is to dump it into a dictionary, and invoke `description` on the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks bshirley! helped me to understand in depth!

Answer (score 17):

```
NSLog(@"%@",hello);
```

Based On data type %@ changes as follows

```
For Strings u use %@
For int  u use %i
For float u use %f
For double u use %lf
```